# xpages list of links to different views

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

There is a `Custom Control` called `layout_main` which contains 4 other custom controls, including a `layout_left` custom control.

The `layout_left` contains 4 links: `All docs`,`By Number`,`By Name` and `By Code`. The first link `By Date` contains a Simple Action Root: Open Page -> Name of page to open: `viewAllDocuments`, which is a Xpage element. `viewAllDocuments` contains the `layout_main` custom control and `ccViewAllDocs` in a facetContent. This custom control ( `ccViewAllDocs` ) contains, finally, the view which lists all the docs + some elementary buttons: New and so on.

My question ( my headache ) is: For the 3 others links should I create 3 others xpages like `viewAllDocuments`? And then modify its facetContent ? If my 'navigator' has 15 links, creating 15 xpages is quite monotonous.

I'm quite new in Xpages development, just being a Lotus Notes developer, and I hope your tips and help will be very helpful. These couple weeks for me since I start learning Xpages is quite an adventure for me: with ups and downs, with big headaches and some little moments of happiness.

I really appreciate your time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the IBM tutorial is a XSLT style sheet to generate an XPage from a view. You could take that approach. You also could use the dynamic view control and compute the view name from an URL parameter, then you only need one page. 
Many possibilities. Ask more!